# algorithm about sliding window

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, treeset, sliding-window

This question is a variant of [k empty slot](https://leetcode.com/problems/k-empty-slots/description/) from leetcode.
the new question is, ask to find the last day when there are k consecutive bloomed flowers.

e.g.
total 7 days, 1 represents flower bloomed，0 represents flower not bloomed, k=3

```
day1：1 0 0 0 0 0 0

day2：1 0 1 0 0 0 0

day3：1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1st time find k consecutive bloomed flowers
```

update:
    lastDayBloomKflowers = 3

```
day4：1 1 1 0 1 0 0

day5：1 1 1 0 1 1 0

day6：1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2nd time find k consecutive boomed flowers
```

update:
    lastDayBloomKflowers = 6

```
day7：1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

finally, flowers will bloom at all position

so the final solution is `lastDayBloomKflowers = 6`

how can we get `lastDayBloomKflowers`? 
the time complexity is `O(nlogn)`, space is `O(n)`

I know how to solve the original leetcode question, I would like to use tree set, but for this variant, I have no idea what data-structure I should use, and efficiently solve it.

Thank you for your time!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am asking for help for the variant of k empty slot problem.

Since the url for k empty slot problem on leetcode is for prime number, and some of you guys may not able to open, I will show you original  k empty slot problem here:

There is a garden with N slots. In each slot, there is a flower. The N flowers will bloom one by one in N days. In each day, there will be exactly one flower blooming and it will be in the status of blooming since then.

Given an array flowers consists of number from 1 to N. Each number in the array represents the place where the flower will open in that day.

For example, flowers[i] = x means that the unique flower that blooms at day i will be at position x, where i and x will be in the range from 1 to N.

Also given an integer k, you need to output in which day there exists two flowers in the status of blooming, and also the number of flowers between them is k and these flowers are not blooming.

Comment: Format the question carefully please.

Comment: I have corrected some typo

Comment: We cannot access the Problem link, seems like it's only for premium users, can you update this post with the question as well. Thank you

Comment: I'm confused. You added a section to your question, "I will show you original problem here:" Is that a description of the problem you'd like help with or a description of the problem you already know how to solve?

Comment: Because some comments said they cannot open the link, because the link is for the prime number in leetcode. The reason why I attached the original one, is trying to make the description more clearly. I know how to solve the original question from leetcode, I am asking help for the variant which I posted at the beginning. I read you genius solution, however, I found some case is not correct, I have already listed the error case below. Could you help me fix that, I will appreciate your time and effort?

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate the day lines to an array representing which position was updated each day:

```
day1：1 0 0 0 0 0 0
array: [None,1] means on day 1, flower 1 bloomed

day2：1 0 1 0 0 0 0
array: [None,1,3] means on day 2, flower 3 bloomed

day3：1 1 1 0 0 0 0
array: [None,1,3,2] means on day 3 flower 2 bloomed

day4：1 1 1 0 1 0 0
array: [None,1,3,2,5]

day5：1 1 1 0 1 1 0
array: [None,1,3,2,5,6]

day6：1 1 1 0 1 1 1 
array: [None,1,3,2,5,6,7]

day7：1 1 1 1 1 1 1
array: [None,1,3,2,5,6,7,4]
```

Now let's iterate over this array with a sliding window:

```
[None,1,3,2,5,6,7,4]
k: 1 |-|  min,max 1
k: 2 |---|  min,max 1,3
k: 3 |-----| min,max 1,3 and count is 3 so days must be consecutive,
             record (1,3) and day 3
k: 3   |-----| min,max 2,5 not consecutive
k: 3     |-----| min,max 2,6 not consecutive
k: 3       |-----| min,max 5,7 and count is 3 so days must be consecutive
                   also 6 is greater than 3 and (5,7) does not
                   overlap with (1,3) so the last day is now
                   known to be 6
k: 3         |-----| min,max 4,7 not consecutive
```

Comment: Yes, I got you, you are genius! Thank you very much. Based on your solution, I come up an optimization for finding min and max in the sliding window, I can use two deques to find min and max when window is sliding, then time complexity is o(n).

Comment: I found a BUG! day1：1 0 0 0 0 0 0

day2：1 0 1 0 0 0 0

day3：1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1st time find k consecutive bloomed flowers
update: lastDayBloomKflowers = 3

day4：1 1 1 1 0 0 0    in your algorithm, it will find day 4 is last day when there is k=3 flowers bloomed, however, day 4 is not valid because, from position 1 to 4, there are 4 consecutive flowers, rather than 3, so final solution should be day3

Comment: @宗天博 3,2,4 is also consecutive. Please clarify more specifically in the question exactly what qualifies as a valid sequence.

Comment: @宗天博 perhaps compare not just the last day, but the last interval - so if the last interval was `(1,3)` you would not accept `(2,4)` as the "last day," but if you find `(4,6)` then you can update. Would that help?